# Dart beginning - unable to run AngularDart Web App template

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Im trying to following the instructions on https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/get-started

I have installed `2.0.0-dev.55.0` in `/usr/lib/dart`.

And have Dartium installed in `/home/bob/Documents/software/dartium-linux-x64-stable-1.24.2.0/chrome`.

When I try **5. Run the app.** I get the following:

[image]

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: angular_app
description: A web app that uses AngularDart
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.51.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0-alpha+12

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0-alpha
  build_runner: ^0.8.8
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0
  test: ^0.12.30
```

I have tried right-click pubspec.yaml and choose `Pub: Get Dependencies` but this didnt make any difference.

I have also tried using the sample dart project from https://github.com/angular-examples/quickstart which uses Dart 2, and NOT using Dartium. But I still get the same error.

When I run  `pub run build_runner serve` I get 
`Could not find bin/build_runner.dart in package build_runner`.

**Building in WebStorm**

When I build using Webstorm, everything looks rosie:

```
Working dir: /home/anton/WebstormProjects/quickstart
/usr/lib/dart/bin/pub global run webdev build --output=web:build
[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph...
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 675ms

[INFO] Checking for updates since last build...
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 808ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart:Running dart2js with --minify --packages=.package-643dc5d58d0e8c6a495fcb24c0476818 -oweb/main.dart.js web/main.dart

[INFO] 1.5s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 2.6s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 3.7s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 4.8s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 5.9s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 7.0s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] 8.1s elapsed, 3/4 actions completed.
[INFO] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart:Dart2Js finished with:

Compiled 9,664,399 characters Dart to 162,915 characters JavaScript in 7.72 seconds
Dart file (web/main.dart) compiled to JavaScript: web/main.dart.js

[INFO] Running build completed, took 9.2s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 271ms

[INFO] Creating merged output dir `build`...
[INFO] Creating merged output dir `build` completed, took 2.9s

[INFO] Writing asset manifest...
[INFO] Writing asset manifest completed, took 3ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 12.3s with 3 outputs (1859 actions)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have also tried using  https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples but still get the same error.

Comment: You're mixing Dart 2 and Dart 1, that's not a good idea. If you use Dart 2, you should use Angular 5-alpha with `build_runner` and Chrome. If you want to use Dartium, then use Dart 1. I'd suggest the former though because the previous is not officially supported anymore. See also https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/ for Angular 5 docs (work-in-progress)

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, I should not use Dartium. Where do I get `Angular 5-alpha` from? And what is `build_runner`?

Comment: Dartium is discontinued and won't be included in Dart 2. In `pubspec.yaml` under `dependencies:` add `angular: "^5.0.0-alpha+12"`. `build_runner` is a tool for code generation that is used by Angular 5 and several other tools. It also replaces `pub serve` and `pub build`.
`

Comment: What URL does the browser open? Try running `pub run build_runner serve` from a terminal and open the URL the command prints. I'm not sure the latest version of IntelliJ already supports `pub run build_runner`.

Comment: I tried running `pub run build_runner serve` but got an error (see updated post).

Comment: Did `Pub: Get Dependencies` result in any errors?

Comment: These examples are more up-to-date https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples (you need to remove the `dependency_overrides:` section in `pubspec.yaml` if you move the projects out of the `angular` Git repo)

Comment: I also tried this git repo but still no joy. I've updated the original posts.

Comment: When building in WebStorm works, running should work as well. Have you tried? What's the output?